# C3.js - Adding Spacing between the X-axis and Legend in Bar Graphs

Tags: javascript, css, c3.js

I have a `C3.js` bar graph and I am trying to add some spacing in between the x-axis and legend in order to avoid the following visual unpleasantry:

[image]

I have already tried to do the following and it has had no effect on the graph:

```
#stacked_bar_chart_container .c3-axis-x {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

I have even tried to do the same thing with `.c3-legend-item` but with a `margin-top: 5px;` instead, but it has still had no effect.

I would also like to note that by removing `#stacked_bar_chart_container` (the `div` container that this graph is binded to) there was still no effect either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the space between the chart and bottom legend by using **padding: {bottom: 20}**, which will add additional 20px between chart and legend. If you place the legend on the right side, you can use **padding: {right: 20}**.

Because padding will make your chart smaller, you may want to adjust the height or width of your chart by using **size: {height: 480}** or **size: {width: 640}**, respectively.

I have created a fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/6jztrbk7/

This is the example JavaScript code:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
   data: {
      columns: [
          ['data1', -30, 200, 200, 400, -150, 250],
          ['data2', 130, 100, -100, 200, -150, 50],
          ['data3', -230, 200, 200, -300, 250, 250],
      type: 'bar',
      groups: [
          ['data1', 'data2']
      ]
   },
   grid: {
      y: {
          lines: [{value:0}]
      }
   },
   legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
   },
   size: {
      height: 300 //adjust chart height
   },
   padding: {
      bottom: 20 //adjust chart padding bottom
   }
});
```